# ajax form and partials

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have successfully added comments to public activity i.e after i followed this tutorial on public activity [#406 Public Activity](http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity?autoplay=true) and i will like the comments to be submitted by ajax, i have tried every tutorial out and does not work my codes so far includes

for the comments controller this is what its like

```
def create
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:activity_id])

    @comment = @activity.comments.create!(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    @users= User.joins(:comments).where(talks: {id:     @activity.talk_ids}).push(@comment.user).reject {|user| user == @comment.user }.uniq
        @users.each do |user|
          @comment.create_activity :create, owner: user
        end
        respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to user_path(current_user), notice: 'Comment created.' }
        format.js
      end
  end
  end
```

for the partial i created for each activity is like this e.g

```
<div class="media social-box">

  <a class="pull-left social-users-avatars" href="#">

    <%= link_to image_tag(activity.user.image.url(:small)) ,activity.user%>
    <p><%= link_to activity.user.username, activity.user if feed.activity %>
      <span style="font-size: 11px; color:#4edee1;">Added this item </span> </p>

  </a>



  <ul class="unstyled custumer_say">
    <li class="clearfix" style="list-style: none">
      <%= link_to  image_tag(sell.image.url,:style=> "width: 40%; padding-right: 10px;", :class=> "pull-left img_client"), sell%>

   <div class="entry-content">
        <header>
          <span class="entry-date">&mdash;  <%="#{time_ago_in_words(sell.created_at)} ago "%> </span>
        </header>


      </div>

    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="media-body social-body">

    <div class="social-footer">

      <div class="social-info-users">
        <strong><%= pluralize(activity.comments.size, "Comment")  %></strong>
      </div>



      <div class="social-comments">


        <ul id="chat">
          <%= render activity.comments %>
        </ul>

        <% if current_user.friends.present? %>

            <div class="media">
              <a class="pull-left" href="#">

                <%=  image_tag(current_user.image.url(:tiny),:style=> "width: 100%;")%>
              </a>
              <div class="media-body">
                <%= form_for([activity, activity.comments.build],:remote => true) do |f| %>
                    <%= f.text_field :details, :class=>"input-block-level", :placeholder=>"write a comment" %>

                <% end%>

              </div>
            </div>


        <% end %>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

all i want to achieve is update this css id

```
<ul id="chat">
              <%= render activity.comments %>
            </ul>
```

also my create.js.erb is something like this

```
$("#chat").append('<%= j render(activity.comments) %>');
$("#new_comment")[0].reset();
```

note, for some reasons this is how my partial is rendered out

```
<%= render activity.comments %> instead of the famous  `<%= render @activity.comments %>`
```

which the other is working properly, and also the whole code is displayed on the current_users showpage e.g users/1 page

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

```
@comment.user = current_user
```

Where does `@comment` get initialized? It looks like you're calling a variable which doesn't exist, unless you've called it in a [`before_action`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) callback?

---

Are you getting any errors? It's hard to go through masses of code without any guidance on what the issue may be. You need to post up some responses / logs from your app to show us how it's dealing with the requests

Comment: there was a typo in ma code you can check the code again i just edited it  thanks for the notice